# Pandas Dataframe filter miss-result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given that `contracts` is a array of `int64`, can anyone tell me why this work:

```py
for c in contracts:
    geoEstab = df.loc[df['id']==c] #geoEstab has results
```

but this returns a empty set:

```py
relevantEstabs = df.loc[df['id'].isin(contracts)] #relevantEstabs is empty
```

Comment: Can you create a small set of data demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: no, i actually just retrieve the first  (and only) row of the set, don't need to append or anything...

Comment: we can tell you if you share an example of it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use the `==` condition, you are matching a criteria given an array, whereas when using the `isin()` function the result will only be true at a location if all the labels match. If values is a Series, that’s the index. If values is a dict, the keys must be the column names, which must match. If values is a DataFrame, then both the index and column labels must match.

Comment: you describe behavior of dataframe `isin` while his code uses series `isin`. Their behaviors and requirements are different